# PEiD alternative on linux

Tags: linux, reverse-engineering, elf

Are there any packer detectors, similar to PEiD that can be used on Linux?
Both for ELF and PE formats.

I have tried to find a similar tool, but all I found is a manual method of searching for strings within the executable, which is not a very efficient and effective method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Detect It Easy**

*Detect It Easy* is more complex, rich and accurate detector than the competitors (in my opinion) which uses "scripts" to detect the type of the program. The detection algorithm of *DIE* is more complex then the others and doesn't use only byte-mask to detect the Compiler/Linker/Packer/etc.

You can read more about *Detect it Easy* in its [Github repository](https://github.com/horsicq/Detect-It-Easy).

Detect It Easy [is available](http://ntinfo.biz/index.html) for Linux machines.

[image]